# How to include an ember app inside a jsp file and serve it using tomcat

Tags: jsp, tomcat, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am new to ember. I am having an ember app which I could run using ember serve and see the output. I want to include this app in a jsp file and run the whole app from tomcat server (i.e., port 8080). I saw in some posts that including handlebars and routes in jsp is possible but I'm unable to get a proper tutorial for it. please provide the correct format for including handlebars and routes in jsp file.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at your existing demands

> the requirement is it should be included in a jsp file like
>   `jsp:include src:some/folder/myapp.hbs please provide a proper format for including handlebars in javascript.

Why does it need to be in a jsp file? Tomcat can serve plain html files just fine. If you really need a `jsp` for some baffling reason, your jsp would need to at least contain the entire contents of the `dist/index.html` file after running `ember build --environment=production`. This would be the sanest of the questionable paths that you're attempting to go down.

I feel like you should take a step back and consider what's going on. Ember is written in Handlebars and ES6 which require compilation/transpilation steps in order to end up as runnable ES5 (and in the case of glimmer, glimmer bytecode). You can't just go importing Handlebars code into jsp's like they're compatible. JSP's also must be converted to html which is handled usually by Jasper within Tomcat. Jasper won't be able to compile handlebars unless if you wrap handlebars in script tags. There's so many reasons, though, that that's not really feasible such as using ember's template compiler with the right scope for the templates, template resolution system in ember, etc...

The standard architecture for Ember/Angular style SPA framework apps is to serve Ember via some channel (nginx, a CDN, your app server) and to have ember communicate with a REST api written in whatever other language you want. Any configuration that needs to be added to your Ember app should generally be done at build time (via `environment.js`) or provided from a REST endpoint.

I use Ember.js with Spring boot. My architecture is a Spring Boot based API that listens on 8080 with an apache SSL terminating reverse proxy in front that serves the Ember app as well. I will switch any day to nginx (but that's neither here nor there for this post).

If you need to add dynamic behavior to a jsp, then I'd recommend you consider using another tool. If you like handlebars, use handlebars directly. Use glimmer.js. Use Vue. This is not really what Ember is meant for at all and it's going to just be pain and work while throwing away many of the productivity advantages of using ember in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a serveable application from Ember you will need to run `ember build -e production`. This will create a `dist` folder with an `index.html` as well as all the javascript,css,etc assets that your app contains. I'm not familiar with tomcat, but you may be able to simple copy/paste this directory somewhere and have tomcat read it which is a good starting point for seeing how the pieces fit together.

Getting this to work well in production usually requires a bit of work.  [Our build process](https://www.jrjohnson.dev/posts/2017-09-06--deploy-story) packages up the application into a zip file and sends it to S3 to be downloaded, parsed, and served by our PHP backend. Your process will probably be different, but hopefully that post will lead you in the right direction.

Comment: I have tried building the app and running the index.html in tomcat, it is working fine. but the requirement is it should be included in a jsp file like <jsp:include src:some/folder/myapp.hbs /> followed by the javascript src added to it. please provide a proper format for including handlebars in javascript.

Comment: I understand why that is an appealing route (I once authored https://github.com/ucsf-ckm/symfony-emberjs-edition for just this purpose), but it probably won't lead you down a very good path. `ember-cli` is constantly re-working it's internal build process to provide you the very best app for your users. If you try and put `hbs` files inside of `jsp` you will be responsible for compiling your javascript yourself (which I'm not sure is reasonable or possible) and will loose one of the main benefits of using Ember.js.